# TypeError when creating a user using Nextjs, Postgresql, Prisma, Firebase Authentication

Tags: javascript, postgresql, firebase, next.js, prisma

Am new to development and i have been trying my best to resolve the issues i face myself to be best i can but this error has been bugging me for a few days now and i can't wrap my head around it

trying to login using google account and goes ok with google auth and i am sent to the onboarding page and once i enter name and about and a profile image and click create account i get the following errors.

The prisma studio is up and running and i do see the columns i had made in the schema ex id, name, email, image etc. but once i hit the create user i get the error and no user is being created

in the inspect console

```
POST http://localhost:3005/api/auth/onboard-user 500 (Internal Server Error)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:251


onboarding.jsx:51 AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
```

and in Vscode the server crashes with the following error in terminal

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'user')
    at onBoardUser (file:///Users/omair/webapplications/2023%20Projects/Whatsapp%20Clone/server/controllers/AuthController.js:29:31)
```

AuthController Page

```
import getPrismaInstance from "../utils/PrismaClient.js";

export const checkUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { email } = req.body;
    if (!email) {
      return res.json({ msg: "Email is required.", status: false });
    }

    const prisma = getPrismaInstance();
    const user = await prisma?.user?.findUnique({ where: { email } });
    if (!user) {
      return res.json({ msg: "User not found", status: false });
    } else {
      return res.json({ msg: "User Found", status: true, data: user });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};

export const onBoardUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { email, name, about, image: profilePicture } = req.body;
    if (!email || !name || !profilePicture) {
      return res.send("Name Email and Image are required.");
    }
    const prisma = getPrismaInstance();
    const user = await prisma.user.create({
      data: { email, name, about, profilePicture },
    });
    return res.json({ msg: "Success", status: true, user });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

onboarding Page

```
import Avatar from "@/components/common/Avatar";
import Input from "@/components/common/Input";
import { useStateProvider } from "@/context/StateContext";
import { ONBOARD_USER_ROUTE } from "@/utils/ApiRoutes";
import axios from "axios";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function onboarding() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [{ userInfo, newUser }, dispatch] = useStateProvider();
  const [name, setName] = useState(userInfo?.name || "");
  const [about, setAbout] = useState("");
  const [image, setImage] = useState("/default_avatar.png");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!newUser && !userInfo?.email) router.push("/login");
    else if (!newUser && userInfo?.email) router.push("/");
  }, [newUser, userInfo, router]);

  const onboardUserHandler = async () => {
    if (validateDetails()) {
      const email = userInfo?.email;
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.post(ONBOARD_USER_ROUTE, {
          email,
          name,
          about,
          image,
        });
        if (data.status) {
          dispatch({
            type: reducerCases.SET_NEW_USER,
            newUser: false,
          });
          dispatch({
            type: reducerCases.SET_USER_INFO,
            userInfo: {
              id: data.user.id,
              name,
              email,
              profileImage: image,
              status: about,
            },
          });

          router.push("/");
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  };

  const validateDetails = () => {
    if (name.length < 3) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  };
  return (
    <div className="bg-panel-header-background h-screen w-screen text-white flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center gap-2">
        <Image src="/whatsapp.gif" alt="whatsapp" height={300} width={300} />
        <span className="text-7xl">PakChat</span>
      </div>
      <h2 className="text-2xl">Create your profile</h2>
      <div className="flex gap-6 mt-6">
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-6 mt-5">
          <Input name="Display Name" state={name} setState={setName} label />
          <Input name="About" state={about} setState={setAbout} label />
          <div className="flex items-center justify center">
            <button
              className="flex items-center justify-center gap-7 bg-search-input-container-background p-4 rounded-lg"
              onClick={onboardUserHandler}
            >
              Create Profile
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Avatar type="xl" image={image} setImage={setImage} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default onboarding;
```

I am trying to create a user using Google auth via firebase. the login page takes me to the onboarding page as intented to create the user and choose an profile image a user name and some description in the about section i've created in the page. but once i hit the create user and get a user created in my prisma database i get an error mentioned above

It's either i am missing something in the code " which is unlikely " as i am following a youtube video. or there is something going on with the database

Comment: I think the problem is after the google login and the user is fetched. the user is not being created in the prisma. hmmmm